# Skip rows for specific time in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

Need a help.
I have two timestamp columns, so basically I want to get the max and min value with a thirD column showing as timedifference. I am skipping any 12.am time so used the syntax below. ANy help how to achieve the third column, timedifference.. It is in DB2.

```
SELECT EMPID,MIN(STARTDATETIME),MAX(ENDDATETIME)
FROM TABLE
WHERE DATE(STARTDATETIME)= '2012-05-15' AND HOUR(STARTDATETIME)<>0 AND HOUR(ENDDATETIME)<>0
GROUP BY EMPID
```

Comment: The simplest way to get the difference of two numbers (including time values) is to subtract one from the other.

Comment: What do you want the time difference in?  It's fairly trivial to get a relative value (like in the existing answer), but not if you're looking for some sort of exact duration (eg milliseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the results from that in an inner select, and use those values to define the `TimeDifference` column.  My knowledge of DB2 is very limited, so I'm making some assumptions, but this should give you an idea.  I'll update the answer if something is drastically incorrect.

```
Select  EmpId, 
        MinStartDate, 
        MaxEndDate, 
        MaxEndDate - MinStartDate As TimeDifference
From
(
    Select  EMPID,
            MIN(STARTDATETIME)  As MinStartDate,
            MAX(ENDDATETIME)    As MaxEndDate
    From    Table
    Where   DATE(STARTDATETIME) = '2012-05-15' 
        And     HOUR(STARTDATETIME) <> 0 
        And     HOUR(ENDDATETIME) <> 0
    Group By EMPID
) A
```

Comment: Not all DB2 versions support the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function, and when they do, the invocation is not as you've shown.

Comment: @mustaccio Ah, that's what I was afraid of.  Is it possible to just subtract them like in your comment to OP?

Comment: Yes, simply subtracting two timestamp values yields the time difference as a decimal number in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.FF

Comment: The condition for `ENDDATETIME` would be difficult to make fully SARGable (you'd need a Calendar table and something for hours), but `STARTDATETIME` can be changed fairly easily.  As it is, the query won't use indices for those columns.